How to work with or unzip large images file that are in zipped files?
I am working with the Diabetic retinopathy dataset, /kaggle/input/diabetic-retinopathy-detection, however the data is very large and zipped into multiple zip files. Does anyone know how I can read these images in for training models?
There is not enough space in the working directory to unzip all the files. I can't unzip them to the 'input' directly as it is read-only, and I can't read the images on the fly.
So far I downloaded all the zip files, unzipped them on local computer (35000 files, 38gb) and used the data locally to build ML models. However, I need to use kaggle GPU's now, but I need help to know how to read the data.
Any help here welcome. Thanks.
